# How to create a default handler for logging using yaml in Python

Tags: python, logging, yaml, python-logging

In Python, how do I create a default handler for all my logging, when the configuration is stored in a yaml file?

My code loads a yaml config file and logs some messages:

```py
import logging
import logging.config
import yaml

from my_function import my_function

# Configure logging
with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

# Get our logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Log some things
logger.debug("Startup debug")
logger.error("Startup error")

# Call a function in a different file
my_function()
```

My `logging.yaml` file looks this:

```yaml
version: 1
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

These logging messages work. However if I call a function in another file `my_function.py` with a different logger, nothing is logged at all:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def my_function():
    logger.debug("my function debug")
    logger.error("my function error")
    print("my_function called")
```

This is because there are no handlers for `my_function`. I can add a handler to my yaml for `my_function` and it works:

```yaml
version: 1
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: DEBUG
loggers:
  my_function:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console]
    propagate: no
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

But for a large project, I don't want to add handlers for each individual file. I'd like to turn things on and off for the entire project. How do I do that?